Fallo al instalar SQL SERVER 2022 en Ubuntu 22.04
Estoy siguiendo los pasos de instalación para sql server 2022 en ubuntu 22.04, anteriormente había logrado instalarlo pero ahora en otro Linux ha sido imposible.
pasos seguidos de: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu2204
Errores: primero se me quedaba pegado en los pasos iniciales de:
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc

aqui se quedaba sin respuespuesta con una espera eterna, no volvia al prompt de la consola.

Poniendo las instrucciones iniciales para ubuntu 20.04, se logro llegar un poco mas adelante y volviendo con los pasos de la version 22.04, me da el siguiente error:
Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 2620:1ec:bdf::69 443] Err:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy InRelease   Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 13.107.246.69 443] Reading package lists... Done W: https://repository.monarx.com/repository/ubuntu-jammy/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details. W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022/dists/focal/InRelease  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 2620:1ec:bdf::69 443] W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022/dists/jammy/InRelease  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 13.107.246.69 443] W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Ejecuta sudo ls y luego ejecuta el comando indicado. Parece que se queda bloqueado porque sudo está pidiendo la contraseña de root por debajo. Si ejecutas  sudo ls primero la mantendra por un rato, pudiendo ejecutar otros sudo sin tener que reingresarlas.

Encontre como solucionarlo, almenos en mi caso.
Se debe hacer una limpieza con los siguientes comandos:
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update
luego de esto, se vuelve a correr los pasos desde el inicio y ya descarga he instala el SQL Server.
